# How to access value of usercontrol in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a web application that assigns time duration  to students in a day. kind of a scheduler.

so for this i have a user control as `TimePeriod` and this control is loaded dynamically on the web page.

But the number of that user control on a page varies so for this i have user a code that dynamically creates a list of user control.

For example purpose i have set `i` value up to 2, actually it varies
Looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    TimePeriod ib = (TimePeriod)LoadControl("TimePeriod.ascx");
    //ib.RightArrowImgUrl = "~/images/wcm-circle-arrow-button.png";
    span_tempList.Controls.Add(ib);

}
```

When user is done making changes for time for all days. i.e. in all user control on page.

the page has a button which takes this changes to database.

but the problem arises here that How to access the values of these text boxes values from the page as it has now been rendered as html.

This is my User Control Code:---

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TimePeriod.ascx.cs" Inherits="ClassManagment.TimePeriod" %>


<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="time3" size="10" value="08:00" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="time4" size="10" value="09:00"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
```

Code Behind of usercontrol:--------

```
 public partial class TimePeriod : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox time3 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox time4 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();


        public string TimeFrom
        {
            get { return time3.Text; }
            set { time3.Text = value; }
        }

        public string TimeTo
        {
            get { return time4.Text; }
            set { time4.Text = value; }
        }
 }
```

**How i can access values of usercontrol ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so:

```
TimePeriod ib = (TimePeriod)LoadControl("TimePeriod.ascx");
string timeTo = ib.TimeTo;
string timeFrom = ib.TimeFrom;
```

Comment: You could keep track of the dynamically added controls in your page putting them on fields and then access them as a regular object.

Comment: That's correct, when you create controls dynamically you have to recreate them on OnInit page event to get their values.

Comment: And also to get the events raised. i.e. your user control is subscribed to the textbox's click event.

Answer (score 1):

On the button click handler, you can have something like this

```
string timeFrom = null;
string timeTo = null;

foreach (Control control in span_tempList.Controls)
{
     if (control is TimePeriod)
     {
         timeFrom = ((TimePeriod)control).TimeFrom.Text;
         timeTo = ((TimePeriod)control).TimeTo.Text;
         // Do something with these values
     }
}
```

Comment: when i try this code it gives me error like this:
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'ClassManagment.TimePeriod'.**
At this Line-------------:

 TimeFrom = ((TimePeriod)control).TimeFrom;

Comment: @user1118932: I found a bug on my code, but it's not related to what you pasted. Please test it again to see what it says.

Comment: No control inside `span_tempList` is TimePeriod it shows.
As after it gets rendered to html it does not know what is TimePeriod all for the above code is Literal i.e HTML

Comment: @user1118932: what type span_tempList is?

Comment: `span_templist` is spna id in which control is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Keep a global array of your dynamically generated user controls in your class and access those stored instances directly as such:

```
public partial class Foo : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   TimePeriod [] timePeriodArray = new TimePeriod[2];

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
         TimePeriod ib = (TimePeriod)LoadControl("TimePeriod.ascx");
         span_tempList.Controls.Add(ib);
         timePeriodArray[i] = ib;
     }

   }
```

then you can access those instances directly.